# Select boolean result of whether a value exists or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select FieldA, " if data exists in table two return true else false "

from Table1 

Left join Table2 on Table1.Id=Table2.Id
```

This is how I currently do the requirement above:

```
Select FieldA, (case when Table2.Table2Id is not null then 1 else 0 End)

from Table1 

Left join Table2 on Table1.Id=Table2.Id
```

Is there any replacement for the "`Case`" statement, to something like `ifExists(Table2.Id)` ?

Comment: There's no `True` in sql, you can cast 1 or 0 to `bit`.

Comment: what's wrong with case as it serves your purpose?

Comment: SQL Server 2012+ has [`IIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213574.aspx) `IIF(table2.table2id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)`

Comment: @TI This is what i'm looking for. Can you please post it as an answer ?

Comment: @almasshaikh I got plenty of checks and i was looking for as a solution with less code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`, i guess you want the strings `True`/`False`, otherwise cast `1`/`0` to `bit`:

```
SELECT Id,
       DataExists = CASE WHEN EXISTS
       (
           SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Id = Table1.Id
       ) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
FROM dbo.Table1
```

For the sake of completeness:

```
SELECT Id,
       DataExists = CAST((CASE WHEN EXISTS
       (
           SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Id = Table1.Id
       ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BIT)
FROM dbo.Table1
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the performance creating a subquery and my solution ?

Comment: @user3340627: in MS SQL-Server the performance is similar. An `OUTER JOIN` also needs to link both tables.

Comment: @user3340627: note that there's a difference. My query always returns one row per Table1-record whereas your approach would return multiple Table1-records if Table2 contains multiple records with that ID.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use isNull as well.

```
Select FieldA, isnull((SELECT 'TRUE' FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.ID = TABEL1.ID),'FALSE') AS columName

 from Table1
```